# htaccess rewrite to root index if no index file found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site with pre-existing index.php files in certain folders. As part of a push to make the site more dynamic, and routing from a centralised index file I want all subdirs on my site to rewrite to the root index.php if no index(php|htm|html) is found in that dir.

```
--+ /
  | /index.php
  +--+
  |  + /subdir1
  |
  |--+
     | /subdir2
     + /subdir2/index.php
```

So that subdir1 will use the root index.php, but subdir2 would use the index.php file that it has in its directory.

I have used a FallbackResource, because thats EXACTLY what I want:

```
#Use root index.php
FallbackResource /index.php
```

However, I had found that when I use that, I get the following error message.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

So I reverted back to the older:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

but I'm unsure how to exclude subdirs that already have a index file present.

```
^!/index\.(php|htm|html)
```

Something like that?

Comment: You can use a Lookaround based regex    ^/(?!ignoreme|ignoreme2|ignoremeN)([a-z0-9]+)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index\.html !-f 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index\.htm !-f 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index\.php !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the most part, but doesn't work on 1st level subdir. Or my explanation wasn't clear enough.

`www.example.com/subdir1 <= doesn't work`
`www.example.com/subdir1/subdir2/etc <=  works`

Comment: Great that works now. Is it possible to add an ignore for .html|.htm files as well? 
Like would it be: 
`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.(php|htm|html) !-f`

Comment: Do you want to ignore only `index.(php|htm|html)` or any `.htm|.htm` file?

Comment: Yea, just the index files `index.(php|htm|html)`

Comment: That doesn't seem to affect `index.html` or `index.htm` files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74107/discussion-between-joe-midi-and-anubhava).